# GeoIP database that will Geo target by US state

Tags: geoip

I am looking for a GEO IP database (Similar to MaxMind GeoLite2 Country and City) that will allow me to identify the US state that the user is coming from in order to target specific content to that user.

Does anyone know how or where I could find such a database/service or solution?

Comment: MaxMind's GeoIP2 and GeoLite2 City databases have subdivisions/regions, including states in the US. Other vendors offer similar solutions, although I am not sure the coverage is any better with them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect high accuracy, unless you're satisfied with country/city precision. It is after all IP based geolocation data and the accuracy varies. It is based on ISP providers or companies that manages the databases(commercial databases may have higher accuracy). Look at an IP location info webtool ( like http://geoipinfo.org/ ) and you'll see approximately where it finds you, and it also provided accuracy at city and country levels - percentage wise. It used the ip2location database for lookups and their precision data.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but as of today, I used http://api.ipstack.com and it's working perfectly.  They have a VERY extensive help examples on their site, but basically you make the call, parse the data and get what you want.

1. First, be sure you have any/all includes (Namespace=System.Xml, System.Net, blah, blah).
2. Second, be sure **not to test on a private network IP** (192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x) because that will always return blank/empty fields and you'll think something is coded wrong.
3. Third, you will need an Acess_Key from ipstack.com ... you can setup a FREE account (10,000 requests a month I think) and get your access code to enter into your string below for API call.  I filled out the form and was up and running in 10 minutes for free.

This worked for me to track visitors to any page:

```
string IP = "";
string strHostName = "";
string strHostInfo = "";
string strMyAccessKeyForIPStack = "THEYGIVEYOUTHISWHENYOUSETUPFREEACCOUNT";
strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

IP = addr[2].ToString();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string strMyIPToLocate = "http://api.ipstack.com/" + IP + "?access_key=strMyAccessKeyForIPStack&output=xml";

doc.Load(strMyIPToLocate);
XmlNodeList nodeLstCity = doc.GetElementsByTagName("city");
XmlNodeList nodeLstState = doc.GetElementsByTagName("region_name");
XmlNodeList nodeLstZIP = doc.GetElementsByTagName("zip");
XmlNodeList nodeLstLAT = doc.GetElementsByTagName("latitude");
XmlNodeList nodeLstLON = doc.GetElementsByTagName("longitude");

strHostInfo = "IP is from " + nodeLstCity[0].InnerText + ", " + nodeLstState[0].InnerText + " (" + nodeLstZIP[0].InnerText + ")";
// Then I do what you want with strHostInfo, I put it in a DB myself, but whatever.
```